# Springboot | Query causes sql Syntax error, when fetching more than one result

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a Problem with my Query, when the result has more then one Entity the Database throws an error, if the Result has only one Entity the Database is returning that entrie.

**Error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ') FROM student LEFT JOIN classes on student.oid =
> classes.student_oid LEFT JOIN f...' at line 1

**Code:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM student " +
            " LEFT JOIN classes on student.oid = classes.student_oid " +
            " LEFT JOIN grade on classes.oid = grade.classes_oid " +
            " WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR MATCH (first_name) AGAINST (:firstName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
            "(:lastName IS NULL OR MATCH (last_name) AGAINST (:lastName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND  " +
            "(:birthDate IS NULL OR birth_date = :birthDate) AND " +
            "(:studentId IS NULL OR MATCH (student_id) AGAINST (:studentId IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
            "(:teacherOid IS NULL OR teacher_oid = :teacherOid) AND " +
            "(:schoolOid is null OR classes.school_oid = :schoolOid) AND " +
            "(:schoolOid is null OR grade.school_oid = :schoolOid)  GROUP BY student_oid " , nativeQuery = true)
            Page<Patient> getPatientsByFirstNameAndLastNameAndIssuerAndFacilityMaria(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName,
                                                         @Param("birthDate") Date birthDate, @Param("studenttId") String patientId,
                                                         @Param("issuerOid") Long issuerOid, @Param("schoolOid") Long schoolOid, Pageable page);
```

**Update:**

if i send a request to this endpoint without the pageable parameters, the function is returning all entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the query you dont write it right, you have missed  , just check next one it is going to work great and also Pageable not work with `nativeQuery=true` you should also add `countQuery=`

Without pagination:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM reservation " +
      " LEFT JOIN classes on student.oid = classes.student_oid " +
      " LEFT JOIN grade on classes.oid = grade.classes_oid " +
      " WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR MATCH (first_name) AGAINST (:firstName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:lastName IS NULL OR MATCH (last_name) AGAINST (:lastName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:birthDate IS NULL OR birth_date = :birthDate) AND " +
      " (:studentId IS NULL OR MATCH (student_id) AGAINST (:studentId IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:teacherOid IS NULL OR teacher_oid = :teacherOid) AND " +
      " (:schoolOid is null OR classes.school_oid = :schoolOid) AND " +
      " (:schoolOid is null OR grade.school_oid = :schoolOid) GROUP BY student_oid ", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Patient> getPatientsByFirstNameAndLastNameAndIssuerAndFacilityMaria(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName,
      @Param("birthDate") Date birthDate, @Param("studenttId") String patientId,
      @Param("issuerOid") Long issuerOid, @Param("schoolOid") Long schoolOid);
```

**UPDATE:**

With Pagination

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM reservation " +
      " LEFT JOIN classes on student.oid = classes.student_oid " +
      " LEFT JOIN grade on classes.oid = grade.classes_oid " +
      " WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR MATCH (first_name) AGAINST (:firstName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:lastName IS NULL OR MATCH (last_name) AGAINST (:lastName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:birthDate IS NULL OR birth_date = :birthDate) AND " +
      " (:studentId IS NULL OR MATCH (student_id) AGAINST (:studentId IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
      " (:teacherOid IS NULL OR teacher_oid = :teacherOid) AND " +
      " (:schoolOid is null OR classes.school_oid = :schoolOid) AND " +
      " (:schoolOid is null OR grade.school_oid = :schoolOid) GROUP BY student_oid ",
      countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation " +
          " LEFT JOIN classes on student.oid = classes.student_oid " +
          " LEFT JOIN grade on classes.oid = grade.classes_oid " +
          " WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR MATCH (first_name) AGAINST (:firstName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
          " (:lastName IS NULL OR MATCH (last_name) AGAINST (:lastName IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
          " (:birthDate IS NULL OR birth_date = :birthDate) AND " +
          " (:studentId IS NULL OR MATCH (student_id) AGAINST (:studentId IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND " +
          " (:teacherOid IS NULL OR teacher_oid = :teacherOid) AND " +
          " (:schoolOid is null OR classes.school_oid = :schoolOid) AND " +
          " (:schoolOid is null OR grade.school_oid = :schoolOid) GROUP BY student_oid ", nativeQuery = true)
  Page<Patient> getPatientsByFirstNameAndLastNameAndIssuerAndFacilityMaria(@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName,
      @Param("birthDate") Date birthDate, @Param("studenttId") String patientId,
      @Param("issuerOid") Long issuerOid, @Param("schoolOid") Long schoolOid, Pageable page);
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, you where right about the missing spaces, i fixed it but unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: if you will replace `Page<Patient>` to `List<Patient>`, is it fetch all values ? i think it will do, because you are using nativeQuery=true and how i know you can`t use pageable with native query. Also remove all pageable params from query and retry. I did update to the answer with query.

Comment: Hi @Andrei Lisa, you are right. 
if i send a request to this Endpoint with Postman and and dont add page and size parameter for this Function, spring returns all enties as a page. But when i add Page and Size parameter it doesnt work anymore.
Do you have an idea how make this funktion (query) work as pagable?

Comment: pageable can't work with `nativeQuery=true`, maybe you will rewrite it to jpql also as `@Query`. I dont think that is a hard one.

Comment: Hi thanks again, i think jpql does not support Match against right?

Comment: what about `LIKE` have you tried to replace `MATCH  AGAINST ` to `LIKE` yet ?

Comment: Hi, yes i was using LIKE before but due to the large amount of data >100 Million Students, the System became to slowly. So i have to use match Against because it is much faster.

Comment: ok, in this case to have a `Pageable` + `nativeQuery` + `MATCH  AGAINST`, you should also declare a new param in `@Query(countQuery = )`

Comment: i`m going to update the answer with an approximate query that you should add

Comment: i just updated the answer and set a final query that is going to work with pagination and nativeQuery